# How to find a match in file and then suffix that match

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file "test.xml"
That looks like the below:

```
CLASS="BAKERS"
GROUP="ABCYYYYY"
TRACK="DASD"
OWNERS="ALPHA"
GROUP="ABCXXXXX"
GROUP="ABCZZZZZ"
```

I want to use a single SED line command to find all occurrences of `GROUP="ABC`
Then within the "" I want add suffix: `_DONE` to all the matches found.

So the result should look like:

```
CLASS="BAKERS"
GROUP="ABCYYYYY_DONE"
TRACK="DASD"
OWNERS="ALPHA"
GROUP="ABCXXXXX_DONE"
GROUP="ABCZZZZZ_DONE"
```

This is the command I am using:

```
`sed -i.bkp '/^GROUP="ABC/ s/$/_DONE"/' test.xml`
```

but it is appending after the " and not within the ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost that. But `$` means end of line so you have to substitute the last `"` using `"$` instead:

```
sed -i.bkp '/^GROUP="ABC/ s/"$/_DONE"/' test.xml
```

you could also specify that there is some blank after the `"` with for instance `"[ \t]*$`

Comment: This is the simplest (thus prefered) way : no need to remember the whole line like some of the other answers do, just like here say `on the lines matching ... , replace the last " with _DONE"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed command

```
sed '/GROUP="ABC/s/\(.*\)"/\1_DONE"/'
```

**Output  :**

```
CLASS="BAKERS"
GROUP="ABCYYYYY_DONE"
TRACK="DASD"
OWNERS="ALPHA"
GROUP="ABCXXXXX_DONE"
GROUP="ABCZZZZZ_DONE"
```

Comment: there is no need to `/g`, since you are doing it just once.

Answer (score 1):

this may help:

```
sed -i 's/^GROUP="ABC[^"]*/&_DONE/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this but without the backticks :

```
sed -i.bak '/^GROUP="ABC/s/"$/_DONE"/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sed  -i.bkp 's/GROUP="ABC[A-Z]*/&_DONE/g' test.xml
```

I tested with your example and worked.